# Using function integral2 with an interpolated function

Tags: matlab

I want to compute the integral of an interpulated function over a 2D triangle.

I wrote the following code:

```
q=integral2(@(xs,ys)interp2(X,Y,v,xs,ys,'linear'),min(xs),max(xs),min(ys),max(ys));
```

I looked at the function' document and couldn't find what does the function do when recived an interpulated function? will it work for me?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you *tried* it?

Comment: yes, it gives a result. but i can't be sure that the result is correct because i dont have the analytic function.